# The impact of input to output in classification

Tags: neural-network, feature-selection

I've designed a classifier using of MLP neural network. The network input has 2000 features and the network output is 6 classes.

**My code:**

```
train_X, test_X, train_Y, test_Y = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=np.random.seed(7), shuffle=True)

train_X = np.reshape(train_X, (train_X.shape[0], 1, train_X.shape[1]))
test_X = np.reshape(test_X, (test_X.shape[0], 1, test_X.shape[1]))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=False, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(train_Y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_X, train_Y, validation_split=.20,
                        epochs=1000, batch_size=50)
```

**Question:** How can I figure out which of the inputs to the network has the most impact on the classification for each class?

Do you have a sample example with Python?

Comment: probably you need to analyze your training data. classifier adjusts itself to the training data provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want [mutual_info_classif](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif.html#sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif)

One thing: There is many feature evaluation, mostly depend on what is your classifier going to do. See [feature_selection](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.feature_selection) of `sklearn` for more information

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the weights after training, although whether that will help depends on the complexity, for example how many hidden layers you have.

Be careful about the assumptions you make one of my favourite stories, possibly apocryphal, is about some work the U.S. military did. They wanted a neural net that recognised whether or not there was a main battle tank in the picture. So they created a set of pictures with and without tanks and after a bit they were getting really good results. Then they tried it on a different set of pictures and it failed abjectly. After some analysis they worked out that the pictures with tanks had blue skies and the pictures without cloudy skies.

Comment: Also have a look at how the weights change with different training sets.